# Python kernel dying while loading pre trained YOLO model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, yolo

I was trying to run coursera's YOLO object detection implementation with webcam live feed on spyder IDE. But, whenever it encounters :

```
yolo_model =load_model("model_data/yolo.h5")
```

kernal dies.

The error shown is :

```
2018 15:18:14.079164: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel‑win\M\windows\PY\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
```

Comment: What you call an error message is not, its just a warning.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro but kernel is dying

Comment: Yes, but you need to provide more information if you want help with your problem, like any error messages and stack traces produced during the crash, and you should also try this code outside of spyder and see if you get any meaningful information.

Comment: It's a warning and kernel's death is more of spyder thing. Just try to run the script from shell.

Answer (score 0):

I get this same error too when I just run that one line (and an import statement before that) in a just loaded python shell. The model file is 200 MB. I have a 16 GB RAM Windows laptop with a GTX 1050 GPU with 4GB VRAM. I also tried running it via my CPU (by first starting a session configured with the device set to cpu).

All I can guess is that Coursera's computers have MUCH more memory than I do.

Comment: LOL you know where it is from. I couldn't find any other implementation of yolo other than coursera's. I followed mark jay's youtube tutorial. But I encountered other errors there. So, were you able to find any working implementation of YOLO?

Comment: I could load the model on a much more powerful  computer (Azure NC6s_v3 with a V100 GPU 16 GB VRAM, 112 GB main memory). However that VM doesn't come with a YAD2K package loaded to run other parts of that code, so installing that is on my to do list.... while figuring out how to do that, I did see comments about recompiling YOLO, so that might work for my laptop.

Comment: For recompiling possibilities see
https://www.coursera.org/learn/convolutional-neural-networks/discussions/weeks/3/threads/NKYyk-3_EeeQAhImpH4WKA/replies/EwcANPPcEeejsA6eWGItZg
and 
https://www.coursera.org/learn/convolutional-neural-networks/discussions/weeks/3/threads/cJdYAHsbEeiFgRIZLeUAAg